# Extract packets from a large pcap file to create a small pcap file

Tags: pcap, tshark

I have a large pcap file (30G).
I also have a CSV file that contains a large number of flow IDs (more than 50000) in the format of
"source_address-destination_address-source_port-destination_port-protocol".

I want to extract packets from the pcap file according to the flow IDs in the CSV file, and create another pcap file.

I know Wireshark can filter packets based on IP address or port, but it can only filter one flow at a time.
I have to filter a larger number of flows (more than 50000) according to the 5-tuple in the CSV file. It looks like Wireshark cannot achieve it.

Is there an efficient way to filter the packets according to the flow ID stored in a CSV file and create a new pcap file?